# Implement multi fields sort on search results in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, search

I have an array of objects like the following 
[{city: "Amsterdam", country: "Netherlands"}, {city: "Norwalk", country: "United States"},
{city: "Norwalk", country: "United States"}, {city: "Unknown", country: "Unknown"}]

I want to implement a search with sort on results such that, when user enters the first alphabet e.g. "n" in the search box, it should display results by the following sort order.
A) cities that start with "n"
B) countries that start with "n"
C) cities that contain "n" 
D) countries that contain "n"

I tried to implement something like this

```
filteredData = gridData.filter(function (rowObj) {
        if (!!filterText) {
           //Filter records with some function. 
           return isSubstringIgnoreCase(filterText, rowObj.city) || isSubstringIgnoreCase(filterText, rowObj.country);
        }
        return true;
    });
    filteredData.sort(function(a,b) {
        var cityA = a.city.toLowerCase(),
            cityB = b.city.toLowerCase(),
            countryA = a.country.toLowerCase(),
            countryB = b.country.toLowerCase();
        filterText = filterText.toLowerCase();
        if(cityA.indexOf(filterText) < cityB.indexOf(filterText) || cityA.indexOf(filterText) < countryB.indexOf(filterText)) {
            return -1;
        } else if(cityA.indexOf(filterText) > cityB.indexOf(filterText) || cityA.indexOf(filterText) > countryB.indexOf(filterText)) {
            return 1;
        } else if(countryA.indexOf(filterText) < countryB.indexOf(filterText) || countryA.indexOf(filterText) < cityB.indexOf(filterText)){
            return -1;
        } else if(countryA.indexOf(filterText) > countryB.indexOf(filterText) || countryA.indexOf(filterText) > cityB.indexOf(filterText)){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

But it is not working as expected. Kindly help me in fixing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37mfG/)
I use:

```
Array . filter ()
```

function to remove duplicates from sort orders: A) - C) and B) - D).
Deleted entries from the search results come from the orders: C) and D).